# Local Active Directory Angular and .NET Core authentication in offline environment

Tags: .net, angular, authentication, active-directory

Running into a bit of a hurdle setting up authentication in an offline environment using local AD with .NET 6.0 and Angular. All the guides I find online are for Azure AD and generally assume the environment I'm in is on the internet.

Is there a guide to setting up an Angular 16 application using .NET 6 backend using local AD in an offline environment? Been googling hard but have not found anything yet, so thought I'd ask here.

Comment: does this help?
https://decovar.dev/blog/2022/06/16/dotnet-ldap-authentication/